# Given a dictionary, find all possible letter orderings

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I was recently asked the following interview question:

> You have a dictionary page written in an alien language. Assume that
>   the language is similar to English and is read/written from left to
>   right. Also, the words are arranged in lexicographic order. For
>   example the page could be: ADG, ADH, BCD, BCF, FM, FN
>   You have to give all lexicographic orderings possible of the character
>   set present in the page.

My approach is as follows:
A has higher precedence than B and G has higher precedence than H.
Therefore we have the information about ordering for some characters:

```
A->B, B->F, G->H, D->F, M->N
```

The possible orderings can be ABDFGNHMC, ACBDFGNHMC, ...
My approach was to use an array as position holder and generate all permutations to identify all valid orderings. The worst case time complexity for this is N! where N is the size of character set.
Can we do better than the brute force approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could construct a (not-necessarily-connected) DAG of the partial orders implied by the words you have, then exhaustively find all the routes from each node (letter) through all other nodes using the rule that you can go to any node except one that's "upstream" of you or any node you've already visited. Hence you can immediately prune any paths where you'd step to a node that has "upstream" of it a node you haven't used yet, beating brute force. There's probably something cleverer, though.

Comment: I don't think you can do better then n!, but identifying if a pattern is valid or not is going to add some complexity, so I don't believe what you're suggesting is `n!`, either. It sounds like `m*n^2 * n!`, where `m` is the number of rules, although you don't really specify how you would validate each one.

Comment: @jswolf19: you can't do better than `n!` for the simple reason that if the input is a single word `ABCDE` then all `5!` orderings are possible, so you have to output them all. But you can hope to do "better" than `n!` by some term that depends what constraints are imposed, accepting that the term is `O(bupkis)` for some inputs. In the best case, where the input is 5 one-letter words, `A B C D E` then we should be able to answer pretty quickly.

Comment: @Steve: your approach will give a valid ordering each time, the graph is traversed. This will eliminate the validation steps. Thanks

Comment: You should make it explicit that you want to do better in the average case since it's clear you can't do better in the worst case.

Comment: it's not clear to me what you're asking.  you talk about worst case, but it also sounds like your implementation is worst case, because you're generating all permutations and then filtering.  so are you asking for better solutions to the general problem?  because you can certainly do better than the worst case in most cases.

Comment: Maybe the idea is to find an answer that is `O(n + k)` where `n` is the size of the input and `k` is the size of the output...  Or to come as close as you can.  Just because `k` can be `n!` does not mean "no efficient algorithm is possible"; it just means you need to express the complexity in terms of both input and output.  (The complexity of many computational geometry algorithms -- e.g. "find all points in that set lying inside this rectangle -- are expressed precisely this way.)

Comment: @andrew: As pointed out by quasiverse, the worst case complexity cannot be better than n!. That's why I am interested in algorithm which can give the best time complexity for the average case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Donald Knuth has written the paper [A Structured Program to Generate all Topological Sorting Arrangements](http://www.cs.ncl.ac.uk/publications/trs/papers/61.pdf). This paper was originally pupblished in 1974. The following quote from the paper brought me to a better understanding of the problem (in the text the relation i < j stands for "i precedes j"):

> A natural way to solve this problem is to let x<sub>1</sub> be an
>   element having no predecessors, then to erase all relations of the
>   from x<sub>1</sub> < j and to let x<sub>2</sub> be an element ≠
>   x<sub>1</sub> with no predecessors in the system as it now exists,
>   then to erase all relations of the from x<sub>2</sub> < j , etc. It is
>   not difficult to verify that this method will always succeed unless
>   there is an oriented cycle in the input. Moreover, in a sense it is
>   the **only** way to proceed, since x<sub>1</sub> must be an element
>   without predecessors, and x<sub>2</sub> must be without predecessors
>   when all relations x<sub>1</sub> < j are deleted, etc. This
>   observation leads naturally to an algorithm that finds **all**
>   solutions to the topological sorting problem; it is a typical example
>   of a "backtrack" procedure, where at every stage we consider a
>   subproblem of the from "Find all ways to complete a given partial
>   permutation x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub>...x<sub>k</sub> to a
>   topological sort x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub>...x<sub>n</sub> ." The
>   general method is to branch on all possible choices of
>   x<sub>k+1</sub>.
>  A central problem in backtrack applications is
>   to find a suitable way to arrange the data so that it is easy to
>   sequence through the possible choices of x<sub>k+1</sub> ; in this
>   case we need an efficient way to discover the set of all elements ≠
>   {x<sub>1</sub>,...,x<sub>k</sub>} which have no predecessors other
>   than x<sub>1</sub>,...,x<sub>k</sub>, and to maintain this knowledge
>   efficiently as we move from one subproblem to another.

The paper includes a pseudocode for a efficient algorithm. The time complexity for each output is O(m+n), where m ist the number of input relations and n is the number of letters. I have written a C++ program, that implements the algorithm described in the paper – maintaining variable and function names –, which takes the letters and relations from your question as input. I hope that nobody complains about giving the program to this answer – because of the language-agnostic tag.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

// Define Input
static const char input[] =
    { 'A', 'D', 'G', 'H', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'M', 'N' };
static const char crel[][2] =
    {{'A', 'B'}, {'B', 'F'}, {'G', 'H'}, {'D', 'F'}, {'M', 'N'}};

static const int n = sizeof(input) / sizeof(char);
static const int m = sizeof(crel) / sizeof(*crel);

std::map<char, int> count;
std::map<char, int> top;
std::map<int, char> suc;
std::map<int, int> next;
std::deque<char> D;
std::vector<char> buffer;

void alltopsorts(int k)
{
    if (D.empty())
        return;
    char base = D.back();

    do
    {
        char q = D.back();
        D.pop_back();

        buffer[k] = q;
        if (k == (n - 1))
        {
            for (std::vector<char>::const_iterator cit = buffer.begin();
                 cit != buffer.end(); ++cit)
                 std::cout << (*cit);
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }

        // erase relations beginning with q:
        int p = top[q];
        while (p >= 0)
        {
            char j = suc[p];
            count[j]--;
            if (!count[j])
                D.push_back(j);
            p = next[p];
        }

        alltopsorts(k + 1);

        // retrieve relations beginning with q:
        p = top[q];
        while (p >= 0)
        {
            char j = suc[p];
            if (!count[j])
                D.pop_back();
            count[j]++;
            p = next[p];
        }

        D.push_front(q);
    }
    while (D.back() != base);
}

int main()
{
    // Prepare
    std::fill_n(std::back_inserter(buffer), n, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        count[input[i]] = 0;
        top[input[i]] = -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        suc[i] = crel[i][1]; next[i] = top[crel[i][0]];
        top[crel[i][0]] = i; count[crel[i][1]]++;
    }

    for (std::map<char, int>::const_iterator cit = count.begin();
         cit != count.end(); ++cit)
        if (!(*cit).second)
            D.push_back((*cit).first);

    alltopsorts(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is **no algorithm** that can do better than O(N!) if there are N! answers. But I think there is a better way to understand the problem:

You can build a directed graph in this way: if A appears before B, then there is an edge from A to B. After building the graph, you just need to find **all possible topological sort results**. Still O(N!), but easier to code and better than your approach (don't have to generate invalid ordering).

Comment: This is true. But in this example, worst case complexity is not what makes difference. If you have large set of data, then you can **more or less efficently** prune the invalid solutions.

Comment: @Rok Totally agree. I don't know why it's an interview question as there isn't any efficient solution.

Comment: While I appreciate of worst-case complexity. Sometimes you have to be realistic. In a coding competition for instance, you may have to account for worst-case complexity. But in a real-life situation you have to realise that efficiency doesn't always equate to good worst-case complexity.

Comment: @Mu: I don't know that either. Maybe because there are many posible solutions and they get to know your style of thinking and your capability of innovativity/creativity.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like this:

1. Look at first letter: **(A -> B -> F)**
2. Look at second letter, but only account those who have same first letter: *(D)*, *(C)*, **(M -> N)**
3. Look at third letter, but only account those who have same 1. and 2. letter: **(G -> H)**, **(D -> F)**
4. And so on, while it is something remaining...  (Look at Nth letter, group by the previous letters)

What is in parentheses is all the information you get from set (all the possible orderings). Ignore parentheses with only one letter, because they do not represent ordering. Then take everthing in parentheses and topologically sort.

Comment: Topological sort will give only one ordering.

Comment: @user434345: true, although if you open the lid on a topological sort implementation, you might find that you can easily identify the points at which it makes arbitrary decisions, and change it to process all possibilities instead of picking one.

Comment: In particular, the topological sort algorithm that enumerates the vertices in order, not the one based on depth-first search.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i admit straight away that i don't have an estimate of time complexity for the average case, but maybe the following two observations will help.

first, this is an obvious candidate for a constraint library.  if you were doing this in practice (like, it was some task at work) then you would get a constraint solver, give it the various pair-wise orderings you have, and then ask for a list of all results.

second, that is typically implemented as a search.  if you have N characters consider a tree whose root node has N children (selection of the first character); next node has N-1 children (selection of second character); etc.  clearly this is N! worst case for full exploration.

even with a "dumb" search, you can see that you can often prune searches by checking your order at any point against the pairs that you have.

but since you know that a total ordering exists, even though you (may) only have partial information, you can make the search more efficient.  for example, you know that the first character must not appear to the "right" of < for any pair (if we assume that each character is given a numerical value, with the first character being lowest).  similarly, moving down the tree, for the appropriately reduced data.

in short, you can enumerate possible solutions by exploring a tree, using the incomplete ordering information to constrain possible choices at each node.

hope that helps some.